# Pandas Join making Unique Column Name

Tags: pandas

When doing a pd.join() I know there is the are the  lsuffix='' and rsuffix='' options.

But I want to assign a unique name to each column.

What is the best way to set a unique  column name?

Thank you.

Comment: You can predict column names using the `lsuffix` etc, and you could use `rename` based on this.

Answer (score 0):

my solutions was to create a name list and just rename the columns at the end.

```
c_name = []

for i in items:

     qs = Items.objects.filter ( id = i ).values ( 'item')
     _df = pd.DataFrame.from_records ( qs )

     df = df.join ( _df.item,  how='outer',  rsuffix= i )

     c_name.append(i.number)


df.columns = c_name
```

cheers.